# Cocoa OSX set cursor during drag operation

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nscursor

When i set the cursor using

```
- (void)draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session willBeginAtPoint:(NSPoint)screenPoint {
   [[NSCursor closedHandCursor] set];
}
```

than very soon after it switches back to the default cursor

During drag the cursor rects seems disables

How to set the cursor during drag & drop operation?

Answer (score 3):

As well as using `set` to change the cursor, you can also use the `NSCursor` methods `push` and `pop` - these don't rely on cursor rects. You simply `push` when you need to set a new cursor, and `pop` when you want to get back to the cursor being used just before your `push` call. In your example, try using `push` when the drag begins, and `pop` in the delegate method that informs you when the drag is ended.

Comment: didn't work for me :(   I also tried to set the new cursor before "pushing"